# meta_query for user ID in array

Tags: meta-query, array, sql

I'm an attempting to query a meta value (array) of user IDs:

```
$meta_query = [
        [
            'key'       => '_votes_round_2',
            'value'     => $current_user->ID,
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        ]
    ];
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm going the wrong way about this as I'm not getting any results and see the following value in my database:

```
_votes_round_2 | a:1:{i:0;i:1;}
```

How can I correctly meta_query to return the post if the current user ID is in the post meta array with key '_votes_round_2'?

Comment: `a:1:{i:0;i:1;}` is [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147). What we see here is the non-empty array of size `1 byte` containing integral `0` at the first key and  integral `1`  at the second. If you are writing a custom function, use the [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) PHP function to get the data in a readable format.

Comment: Thanks @Max Yudin. Is there a better way to store this data that you would recommend? I'm using 'update_post_meta' which I guess is serializing the value for me. I want to store an array of user IDs in this single meta value if possible.